No wifi Ubuntu 20.04
I'm a complete novice in Ubuntu, although I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an old laptop which went straightforward, and don't know programming language either.(I just read threads and follow/copy the instructions)
I recently replaced my laptop's (HP pavilion 17" Beatsaudio) RAM (from 6GB to 16GB) and put a new SSD hard disk in, because it was getting really slow, although everything functioned, including wifi.
With a bootable usb-stick I installed Ubuntu 20.04. But since then I don't manage to make wifi working. I don't think I damaged anything while swapping RAM and SSD.
After searching I found and tried several solutions, but nothing worked. I also tried Ubuntu 20.04 but same result: no wifi found.
Then I found what I believed the 'exact' problem that I have (because the person wrote about the identical 'broadcom device, including type' that I have. So just to be sure I didn't mess anything up in my previous attempts, I 'freshly reinstalled Ubuntu 24.04' and then followed this thread exactly.
https://github.com/Niels-van-den-Hork/ubuntu-wifi-broadcom-bcm43142-802.11b-g-n
which led me to:
Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers
(the steps in this last link I also saw in several youtube video's.)
Unfortunately still no WIFI.....
Does anybody have a step by step explanation/solution for me? I can make printscreens of certain basics/info if necessary. Here's a few that I 'used' already during my search for a solution:
lspci -vnn | grep Network
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

-------------------

iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

--------------------

udo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version (6.30.223.271+bdcom-23ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

--------------------

UNDER THIS ONE THERE'S A LOT OF INFO, BUT THE PART REGARDING BROADCOM:
lshw
*-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 memory:b2500000-b25fffff
           *-network UNCLAIMED
                description: Network controller
                product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
                vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:b2500000-b2507fff
*-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:43 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:b2400000-b24fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                logical name: eno1
                version: 08
                serial: 6c:c2:17:63:40:3c
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation

-------------------------

rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked



What does this command reveal in terminal mokutil --sb

SecureBoot enabled

The driver won't load with Secure Boot enabled

super! found it and fixed it, tx a lot!
